# Question regarding React-Redux and Thunks

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to figure out the best approach to dispatching two actions within the same thunk function but am drawing a blank (probably because I've been looking at it for a couple of hours)...

So in my `redux/thunks/auth.js` file, I have two functions, one to login the user and one to get the user information. I'd like to call `attemptLogin` and within that after successful login invoke the `attemptGetUser` to load the user's information immediately following the login.

Any ideas on how I can approach this?

**redux/thunks/auth.js**

```
export const attemptGetUser = () => async (dispatch) => {
  await getUser().then((res) => {
    dispatch(setUser(res.data));
  });
};

export const attemptLogin = (formData) => async (dispatch) => {
  await postLogin(formData)
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch(login(res.data));
    })
    .then(() => {
      dispatch(attemptGetUser());
    });
};
```

**redux/actions/auth.js**

```
export const login = (user) => ({
  type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  payload: user,
});

export const setUser = (user) => ({
  type: USER_LOADED,
  payload: user,
});
```

Comment: I think you can make another action that dispatches these two thunk actions in sequence and awaits for each and then dispatch that action

Comment: Any ideas on syntax for that?

Comment: In your action it would probably be something like `await dispatch(attemptLogin(formData));` followed by `await dispatch(attemptGetUser());` however you might need to do a `return dispatch` in your thunks (in the then part) to ensure the promises are chained

Comment: I updated my OP with the code I now have that seems to work great. Thanks!